# How to write a java program to accept the full name of a person and output the last name with initials?

Tags: java

I've written the following code. This works if only there are two initials before last name. How do i modify it to work with 3 or more initials. For example:

`Input: ABC EFG IJK XYZ`

```
Output I want is: A E I XYZ
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Name{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Please enter a Firstname , MiddleName & Lastname separated by spaces");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
        String[] arr = name.split(" ",3);
        System.out.println(arr[0].charAt(0)+" "+arr[1].charAt(0)+" "+arr[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop and don't limit the split to 3 :

```
{
      System.out.println("Please enter a Firstname , MiddleName & Lastname separated by spaces");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println(name);
      String[] arr = name.split(" ");
      // print all the initials
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
          System.out.print(arr[i].charAt(0) + " ");
      }
      // print the last name
      System.out.println(arr[arr.length-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class SName
{ 
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String n;
   Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the user name:");
   n=c.nextLine();
   String [] t=n.split(" ");
   int l=t.length;
   System.out.print("Your Short name:");
   for(int i=0;i<l-1;i++)
  {
   System.out.print(t[i].charAt(0)+".");
  }
    System.out.print(t[l-1]);
  }
 }
```

Try This code
 More [Java Program](https://www.programmingshortcut.com)